# Lazy Load Collection Images in Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'm trying to lazy load all the images in collection listings as seen here:

http://trophymonk.com/collections/mascot-trophies

password: iclabe

So far I'ved done the following:

1.)Called the jquery.lazy.js in my header

2.)Edited my product loop html, changing the  tag to include the data-original attribute, the placeholder url to the src attribute and added the "lazy" class.

3.) Added script before the closing body tag.

The browser is only loading the placeholder images.

Any idea why?

Here's an example of a shopify store with lazy load properly implemented:
http://www.spargogolf.com/collections/new-clubs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an errant '}' at line 1427. You can see this by using the error console of your browser. You might also want to check out http://validator.w3.org/ to make sure your markup is good.

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you be more specific..I just checked the console using google chrome dev tools and it just says: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)."

It looks like it can't find the image url that's stored in the data-original attribute.

Comment: Trying to implement this and learn jquery at the same time...Any idea on debugging or testing this? When I call the $('.lazy') in the console I see it shows me all the <img> tags with that class, but it's not replacing the placeholder img with the data-original url.

Comment: It looks like the version of the jquery library and the version of lazy load plugin were not compatible. I've solved this. Thank you.